# TeXnicCenter hangs on pdf build

Tags: pdf, miktex, compiling, windows, texniccenter

I am having the issue that when I try to build any file that includes => pdf, teXnicCenter immediately hangs, eventually builds, hangs again, eventually opens Adobe, hangs again, eventually opens the pdf.

Using: Miktex 2.9 64bit, TexnicCenter 2.02 64bit, on Windows 7 Home Premium, Adobe Reader X

What I've tried: 
Restarting TeXnicCenter - hangs
reinstalling TeXnicCenter - hangs
restarting computer - hangs
rebuilding all formats in mixtex and updating database - hangs
turning off bibtex and makeindex - hangs
compiling a hello world file - hangs
just building, not viewing - hangs

successful builds:
latex => DVI
building in TexWorks

I was wondering if it was partially due to some large graphics, and that fact that => DVI works fine seemed to suggest that, but a basic test program with no figures has the same issue. It compiles fine in TeXWorks, though I prefer working in TeXnicCenter, so I'm hoping someone can point out what I am doing wrong here...

Also, TeXnicCenter was compiling fine earlier this evening (yesterday evening...?), so something changed?

I'm not getting any error messages, but let me know if a .log file would help...

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Cartesian closed categories and the price of eggs}
\author{Jane Doe}
\date{September 1994}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you see anything odd or unusual in the `.log` file? Does the problem go away, if you use another PDF reader than Adobe Reader?

Comment: I tried installing FoxIt just now and changed the build profile for Latex => PDF, but it seems to not have made any difference. The fact that it is hanging before it even attempts to compile makes me think that it is not a viewer issue...

Comment: Also I don't see anything odd in the .log file - not that I would really know what to look for if it didn't blatantly say something about huge amounts of data or errors in handling things...some external fonts were loaded, that's about it:

Comment: Also just now I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Miktex to no avail.

Comment: Ok, I think I found it! I reinstalled MikTex, this time creating a MikTex folder in C:, rather than the default installation into Program Files (I also reinstalled ghostscript and gsview at the same time, but I am assuming it was the first). Reinstalled TexnicCenter again, and everything seems to be working!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that has been solved by re-installing the distribution.

Comment: Actually, I am sorry to post once more when this thread seems to have been closed, but it seems like the reinstall in a new folder was not the solution; the problem seems to be compiling anything to pdf when Spotify is also open. Please let me know if others are having this issue.